# WiFi HotSpot Battery consumption for 2.4GHz vs 5GHz vs 6Ghz?

Tags: battery-life, wifi-hotspot, android-13

On my phone I can configure WiFi HotSpot between 2.4GHz and 5GHz and 6GHz, does this setting have any noticeable effect on battery consumption?

(It's a Samsung Galaxy S22 Ultra, and interestingly, iirc this setting did not exist in Android 12 and was only added when I updated to Android 13)

Comment: Why don't you try it out? I am not sure if this question can be answered as it may depend a lot of factors which Wifi frequency range is best, like distance between hotspot and device(s), how much data is transmitted in which time and how often, how occupied are the used frequencies (collisions), the used chip and if I remember correctly in 6GHz the max. transmission power depends on where you are located.